# Как заменить все адреса ссылок в тексте?

Tags: php

Есть строка с html-кодом, например:

```
<p>Текст текст текст <a class="link" href="https://google.com/">ссылка</a>, текст текст текст <a href="#top" title="title">ссылка</a></p>
```

Как через php заменить все значение href на свое? Чтобы получилось:

```
<p>Текст текст текст <a class="link" href="https://domain.com/">ссылка</a>, текст текст текст <a href="https://domain.com/" title="title">ссылка</a></p>
```

Comment: Распарсить через `preg_match` и поменять

Comment: Это понятно, а как составить регулярное выражение для этого, не понятно.

Comment: @Frontender шаблон [`~href="\K[^"]+~`](https://regex101.com/r/LnniKM/1) и функция preg_replace().